# Convert python http Library code to Socket without http library

Tags: python, sockets, http

I Tried to convert the below code to Socket without http library, Receive response is not same as using http library. Please help me to convert the code to socket.
IN webserver the request be like this:
http://192.168.1.15/api/v2.0.0/status

```
import http.client

conn = http.client.HTTPConnection("192,168,1,15")

payload = ""

headers = {
    'Content-Type': "application/json",
    'Authorization': "Basic YWRtaW46OGM2OTc2ZTViNTQxMDQxNWJkZTkwOGJkNGRlZTE1ZGZiMTY3YTljODczZmM0YmI4YTgxZjZmMmFiNDQ4YTkxOA=="
    }

conn.request("GET", "api,v2.0.0,status", payload, headers)

res = conn.getresponse()
data = res.read()

print(data.decode("utf-8"))
```

Response to be in Json:

```
{
    "allowed_methods": null,
    "battery_percentage": 100,
    "battery_time_remaining": 136800,
    "distance_to_next_target": 0,
    "errors": [],
    "footprint": "[[0.506,-0.32],[0.506,0.32],[-0.454,0.32],[-0.454,-0.32]]",
    "joystick_low_speed_mode_enabled": false,
    "joystick_web_session_id": "",
    "map_id": "36c89a77-57a7-11e9-b33b-94c691a7386a",
    "mission_queue_id": null,
    "mission_queue_url": null,
    "mission_text": "Starting...",
    "mode_id": 7,
    "mode_key_state": "idle",
    "mode_text": "Mission",
    "moved": 225.17,
    "position": {
        "orientation": -139.83770751953125,
        "x": 14.193017959594727,
        "y": 31.63810920715332
    },
```

Comment: This is not *"Please __help me__ to convert the code to socket"* but "please __do everything for me__"*.  If you want to get help with your work then show what you did so far and where you have problems, i.e. code, what you expect and what you got instead. Also note that HTTP is not that simple protocol you might think. So you better add a reason why you cannot use an existing http library but must reinvent the wheel again (and probably without having sufficient knowledge to do so).

Comment: @Pavel Anilhoski ,Thanks for your Comments. As you suggested Here i attached the code what i tried, import socket

server = ("192.168.1.15", 80)
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect(server)
msg  = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n"
msg += "Host: 192.168.1.15:80\r\n"
msg += "Path: /api/v2.0.0/status\r\n"
msg += "Content-Type: application/json\r\n"
#msg += "Connection: close\r\n"
msg += "\r\n"
sock.sendall(msg.encode())
data = sock.recv(50000)
sock.close()
print(data.decode())

Answer (score 0):

```
Here i attached the code what i tried, 

import socket

server = ("192.168.1.15", 80)
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect(server)
msg  = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n"
msg += "Host: 192.168.1.15:80\r\n"
msg += "Path: /api/v2.0.0/status\r\n"
msg += "Content-Type: application/json\r\n"
msg += "Connection: close\r\n"
msg += "\r\n"
sock.sendall(msg.encode())
data = sock.recv(50000)
sock.close()
print(data.decode())

Server Response in html format, expected json format which shown in above,

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 22 Oct 2019 13:36:51 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=rktgr2p1mu3qnu1he1msjij7a5; expires=Thu, 24-Oct-2019 
13:36:51 GMT; Max-Age=172800; path=/
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Mir-Page-Id: 6ef0b1a
Set-Cookie: mir-auth-token=deleted; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; Max- 
Age=0; path=/
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=deleted; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; Max- 
Age=0; path=/
Set-Cookie: mir_user_id=0; expires=Tue, 22-Oct-2019 13:35:51 GMT; Max-Age=0; 
path=/
Set-Cookie: mir_user_shortcode=deleted; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; 
Max-Age=0; path=/
Vary: Accept-Encoding
 Connection: close
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

2007
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="Content-Type" content="text/html">
<meta name="keywords" content="">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="Mobile Industrial Robots ApS">
<meta name="owner" content="Mobile Industrial Robots ApS">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, 
initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent">
<meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">

The reason I working without http library because I wanna use socket code in my 
PLC Programmming, In PLC don't have http library to communicate with this 
server,PLC already have socket communication.

Hope Can Support me,Thanks in Advance.
```

Comment: The reason I working without http library because I wanna use socket code in my 
PLC Programmming, In PLC don't have http library to communicate with this 
server,PLC already have socket communication.

Hope Can Support me,Thanks in Advance